# How to add extra space between the left-side legend and the left parenthesis of a matrix in the presence of a vertical line?

Tags: matrices, arrays, block, blkarray

I have the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{blkarray}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}\label{cexA_Rmat}
\mathbf{R}=
\begin{blockarray}{cccccc}
& \lambda_1 & \lambda_2 & \lambda_3 & \lambda_4 \\
\cmidrule{2-6}
\begin{block}{c|(ccccc)}
  \tau_1 &           -1 & \phantom{-}1 & \phantom{-}0 & \phantom{-}0 \\
  \tau_2 & \phantom{-}0 &           -1 & \phantom{-}1 & \phantom{-}0 \\
  \tau_3 & \phantom{-}0 & \phantom{-}0 & \phantom{-}1 &           -1 \\
  \tau_4 &           -1 & \phantom{-}0 & \phantom{-}0 & \phantom{-}1 \\
\end{block}
\end{blockarray}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

where I would like to add extra space between column $\tau_i$ (i=1,2,3,4) and the left-side matrix parenthesis. As you can see in the enclosed image, there the left parenthesis and the vertical line are totally overlapped. How can I increase their distance (as well as the distance between the $\tau_i$s and the vertical line)?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Insert a space within the column specification of your `blockarray`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{blkarray}

\begin{document}

\[
  \mathbf{R} =
  \begin{blockarray}{ cccccc }
    & \lambda_1 & \lambda_2 & \lambda_3 & \lambda_4 \\
    \cmidrule{2-6}
    \begin{block}{@{} c @{\hspace{1ex}} | @{\quad} (ccccc) }
      \tau_1 &           -1 & \phantom{-}1 & \phantom{-}0 & \phantom{-}0 \\
      \tau_2 & \phantom{-}0 &           -1 & \phantom{-}1 & \phantom{-}0 \\
      \tau_3 & \phantom{-}0 & \phantom{-}0 & \phantom{-}1 &           -1 \\
      \tau_4 &           -1 & \phantom{-}0 & \phantom{-}0 & \phantom{-}1 \\
    \end{block}
  \end{blockarray}
\]

\end{document}
```

Also note the removal of the inter-column space (using `@{}`) at the beginning of the nested `block`.

Comment: Thanks, you helped a lot!

Answer (score 2):

With `{pNiceArray}` of `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}

\begin{document}

\[\mathbf{R}=
\begin{pNiceArray}{cccc}[first-col,first-row]
      & \lambda_1 & \lambda_2 & \lambda_3 & \lambda_4 \\
\hline 
\noalign{\vskip2pt}
  \tau_1 &           -1 & \phantom{-}1 & \phantom{-}0 & \phantom{-}0 \\
  \tau_2 & \phantom{-}0 &           -1 & \phantom{-}1 & \phantom{-}0 \\
  \tau_3 & \phantom{-}0 & \phantom{-}0 & \phantom{-}1 &           -1 \\
  \tau_4 &           -1 & \phantom{-}0 & \phantom{-}0 & \phantom{-}1 \\
\CodeAfter
\tikz \draw ([xshift=-2pt]1-|1) -- ([xshift=-2pt]5-|1) ;
\end{pNiceArray}\]

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]